# How to pass viewmodel to ajax success method and redirct to new page alone with the viewmodel

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

What I'm trying to do using jQuery&Ajax is to collect data(as an object) from this first form and 1)keep the data or 2)post them to ASP.NET controller(a viewmodel will receive the data from that object) and then redirect to new page 1)alone with this object or 2)with the viewmodel that passed from controller(because I need the data to compelet another form).

The code for the first form:

```
    $('.submit').on('click', function (event) {
            // some irrelevant logic;


            var viewModel = { DayName: picked_dayName, DayNumber: picked_day, Month: picked_month, StartTime: picked_startTime, EndTime: picked_endTime };

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Venue/Datepicking',
                data: viewModel,
                cache: false,
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function toDetailPage(data) {
                    if (data.IsDataValid) {
                        window.location.href = '/Venue/ContactDetail';
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

The code in controller for the view:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult DatePicking(BookingDataTimeViewModel viewModel)
    {
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

The code in controller for the new page I was trying to direct to:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult ContactDetail(BookingDataTimeViewModel viewModel)
    {
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

The problem is I always back to home page onec click hte submit button. Pleas show me a way to compelet this or any solution that solves this. Thanks in advance.

I use the code below instead the ajax:

```
$.post('/Venue/Datepicking', viewModel, function (result) {
    window.location.href = '/Venue/ContactDetail';
});
```

But the result is still the same.

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the **same** page. If you want to redirect, make a normal submit (do not use ajax)

Comment: And your `DatePicking()` method is returning a view (html) not json so your code would throw an error

Comment: `$.post()` **IS** ajax :)